# date data is null, when i try to use parse to define time format

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, datetime-format

I just can not read in date in d.date. Here is my code.

```
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%e/%_m/%Y %H");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("../datasets/Book1.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate.parse(d.dateHour);
            d.estPressure = +d.x_inf;
            d.lowPressure = +d.m1std;
            d.upPressure = +d.p1std;
        });
    console.log(data);
```

And here is my csv data look like

tHour,x_inf,p1std,m1std,dateHour

1,10,10.3,9.2,1/5/2016 00

2,12,16.8,7.2,1/5/2016 01

3,14,21.2,6.8,1/5/2016 02

4,15,19.8,10.2,1/5/2016 03

5,14.5,16.9,12.1,1/5/2016 04

6,18,22.96,13.04,1/5/2016 05

7,18.76666667,24.04666667,13.48666667,1/5/2016 06

8,20.15238095,25.75238095,14.55238095,1/5/2016 07

9,21.53809524,27.45809524,15.61809524,1/5/2016 08

10,22.92380952,29.16380952,16.68380952,1/5/2016 09

11,24.30952381,30.86952381,17.74952381,1/5/2016 10

12,25.6952381,32.5752381,18.8152381,1/5/2016 11

13,27.08095238,34.28095238,19.88095238,1/5/2016 12

14,28.46666667,35.98666667,20.94666667,1/5/2016 13

15,29.85238095,37.69238095,22.01238095,1/5/2016 14

I do not know if I have defined the wrong format..Can anyone help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%_` is space padded. See [doc](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).
Use `%-` instead:

```js
var dates = [
  '1/5/2016 00',
  '1/5/2016 01'
];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%-d/%-m/%Y %H");

dates.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(parseDate.parse(d));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```